# Count number of lines on a page

Tags: logging

Is there a way to count the number of lines printed on a page without actually counting? (Can one choose to have this written to the log file for every page?)

Comment: Counting without counting? Do you mean count without printing?

Comment: I mean can I make TeX save me the trouble of counting with my index finger.

Comment: The concept of “number of lines in a page” is quite vague in the presence of displayed equations, lists, quotations and other things. Are you looking for a method for knowing the maximum number of lines (assuming no change in font size in the middle) on a page?

Comment: Package `\usepackage[lineno]{lineno}` is a help, but it displays the line numbers, but it can be switched off in the real production run. Take care with math environments, however